# Initializing empty state that will receive a number in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React controlled form, what is the correct initial value for a number input?

If I set `myNumber` to `''`, `[]`, or `{}`, it works, but onChange the value becomes `"25"` instead of `25` and then I have to convert it back to an integer. If I set it as `0` my input loads with a 0 as its value and I'd rather the input load empty.

What's the best way to do this?

**Edit:** The comments and answers below all focus on setting/converting the value on change. My question is to confirm whether or not that's the only option. If it were an array, we'd start with an empty array; an object would start as an empty object; a string would start as a blank string.

Is the only way to initialize state of a number to set it as another type and then convert it?

```
class NumberForm extends Component {
  state = {
    myNumber: ''
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="myNumber"
          value={this.state.myNumber}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**2022 Edit: How I'd handle this today...**

Use Hooks & TypeScript

```
const NumberForm: React.FC = () => {
  const [myNumber, setMyNumber] = useState<number>()

  return (
    <form>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="myNumber"
        value={myNumber}
        onChange={e => setMyNumber(e.target.value)}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: When you start with the integer 0, does the updated value remain an integer?

Comment: Try this `this.setState({ [name]: parseInt(value) })`

Comment: set myNumber default to 0 and value in your input to `this.state.myNumber != 0 ? this.state.myNumber`

Comment: In case of your field hase numeric value then you can directly use 0 as initial value but you will see that 0 value as initial in text box that's the issue.

Comment: In case of you use *' '*  then it will consider as empty value so it will not display anything in text box but consider as string value when assign.

Comment: end of day you read value from event.target.value which is going to be string only so parsing is needed use parseInt(value, 10)

Comment: In case of you use *[]* then it will consider as an array, so this option is totally use-less.

Comment: In case of you use *{}* then it will consider as JSON value. so best way to keep numeric value as initial value is *0* or *' '*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parse the int as the value is getting read from the event.target.value which will always give you string

```
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({ [name]: parseInt(value, 10) })
  }
```

Comment: good answer, but we need to consider string values in state also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt` when use the setState:

```
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({ [name]: parseInt(value) })
  }
```

But maybe is necessary to valid the value before execute parseInt, because can happen a error like `Received NaN for the`value`attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.`

So maybe with `try/catch` can solve your problem:

```
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target

    try {
      this.setState({ [name]: parseInt(value) })
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({ [name]: 0})
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class NumberForm extends Component {
  state = {
    myNumber:parseInt('')
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
//this.setState({ [name]: parseInt(value, 10) })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="myNumber"
          value={this.state.myNumber}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

This could works for starting your state and html element in empty

Answer (score 0):

Here we GO **SOLUTION** for this problem is you can parse the value of state in handler function.

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
       
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: parseInt(event.target.value, 10) })
      }
```